# how to use command line to connect mysql database, and the database name with Illegal character ‘-’?

Tags: mysql

Recently we want to backup mysql data to other database.I have found a problem,
The old database name have Illegal character ‘-’, and I have use command line to connect the database, and I change the database, like: use test-server, but have error as 
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-server' at line 1
This is because of the Illegal character ‘-’, how can I escape this character?
BTW: we can connect database by navicat, but I want login to mysql server to backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password 'db-name'
```